# Given,$A={{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^4+y^2\le1}},B={(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^6+y^4\le1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Then

A. $B \subseteq A$

B. $A \subseteq B$

C.Each of the sets $A-B,B-A \space and \space A\cap B \space  $ is not empty

D.None of the above

I am absolutely clueless on this as I tried to draw two graphs but cannot understand the concept. Will anybody please care to explain?

Graph of $x^6+y^4 \le 1$
[image]

[image]

Graph of $x^4+y^2\le 1$

From this I can conclude that $A \subseteq B$

Comment: What do the two graphs look like? Is one region sitting inside another region?

Comment: Yes due to fear of downvotes I am unable to show the picture by taking a snapshot as they are too hazy but they are sitting on top of the other but it still is confusing as I cant understand between options A and B

Comment: One of the two regions is contained inside the other. That translates into a statement about the sets. Use that to decide which of the options is true.

Comment: I conclude that $A \subseteq B$ based on that but in an exam how can one plot this without using graphing devices. Its tedious and will consume so much time! That's why I wanted a strong solution to prove my point.

Comment: @ OnceUponACrinoid Please see my edit section for the graphs. I later found a plotter whose snapshot I pasted in my edit section. Please see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\;x^4 \le 1 - y^2 \le 1\,$, so $\,x^4 \le 1 \iff |x| \le 1\,$, and the same goes for $\,|y| \le 1\,$. Then use that for all $|a| \le 1 \implies a^6 \le a^4\le a^2\,$.

Comment: But @dxiv this is exactly what I thought if $x^4 \geq x^6$ and $y^2 \geq 
 y^6$ Then A contains B and then $B \subseteq A$. Am I wrong? But this is not right according to the graphs.

Comment: `Then A contains B` Why? You have $\,x^6+y^4 \le x^4+y^2\,$, so $\,(x,y) \in A \implies (x,y) \in B\,$.

Comment: Oh yes yes thanks I got it I got it. So stupid of me !! Stupid Stupid Stupid me!!!!!

Comment: @Saradamani When in doubt, write it down in small steps. It is tempting to mentally translate $\,\le\,$ directly into $\,\subseteq\,$, but in this case it's also wrong.